# How can i make correct URL rewrite condition?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

I have to add some rules in rewrite.config for some pages that doesn't exist anymore. I added the conditions in the following patters, but they are not working:

```
<rule name="_Offisielt_nettsted" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="_Offisielt_nettsted$" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.example.com$‎" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```

The initial broken url is <www.example.com/_Offisielt_nettsted> and i want to redirect to the homepage. Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: You can easily help yourself, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: @Lex Li, unfortunately I already saw the page, and it doesn't help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds just like a charset issue. I just replaced the domian name. But rewrite module say <www.jokies.com> doesn't match regex expression ^www.jokies.com$.

It return
[image]

So I rewrite the ^ and $ and it works

```
<rule name="_Offisielt_nettsted" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="_Offisielt_nettsted$" />
    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.example.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```

[image]

Comment: how did you rewrite the ^ and $?

Comment: @StefanaB I just  remove ^ and $ then re-input  them from my side. It seems there was some difference when you input them even they look the same.

Comment: interesting! I will definitely try that. Thank you!

Comment: Usually you need an editor like Notepad++ and reveal all invisible characters so as to detect such issues. The cause is that by copying such things over the Internet, you don’t know what that web page might insert to break the actual copied text.